# Creating a folder with the %computername% inside Windows Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I'm trying to turn on PowerShell Transcription in our network, and I want to save all the directory in a file server with the computername.
I'll try to use the gloabl variables but it's not funtions; the system create the directory but it write %COMPUTERNAME% and not the real PC name.

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2uHn.png)

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjJEz.png)

You have any idea how can i solve this problem without use PowerShell script or similar?

Comment: PowerShell makes no attempt to expand env variables in the transcription path, you'll have to run a script on the receiving end to rearrange the log files

Comment: Are you using single or double quotes?  With single quotes the variable name %ComputerName% is not getting substituted.  Try double quotes.

Comment: %COMPUTERNAME% is cmd not powershell.

Comment: even if the path is substituted then the syntax in powershell is `$env:computername` and not `%COMPUTERNAME%`